# System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger on quote-line items, in that line iteams i have a field called update__c 
when all values are true and sss condition at that time it updating the parent check box
when my webservice is called and they send multiple records at that time my Update__c field 
is not updating due to the tigger i am getting an Error, while using webservice when we send single Update value at that time it is working.for multiple it is showing an error

Trigger.targerquaote: line 24, column 1
System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject
at line

Below line **Quote__c  quote=[select id, name,Sys_checkchild__c from Quote__c   where Id IN:quoteidset ];**

```
trigger targerquaote on Quote_Item__c (after update, after insert) {
    set<id>idset = new set<id>();
    set<id>quoteidset = new set<id>();
    for (Quote_Item__c  qq : trigger.new) {
        idset.add(qq.id);
        quoteidset.add(qq.Quote__c);
    }


    Quote__c  quote = [select id, name, Sys_checkchild__c from Quote__c   where Id IN:quoteidset ];//Error here
```

Comment: Your query is returning a List but you are trying to assign them into a single instance.

Answer (score 7):

Select statement in SOQL returns list of objects by default.

You should be always following this pattern:

```
List<Quote__c> quotes = [select id, name, Sys_checkchild__c from Quote__c where Id IN :quoteidset ];
if (quotes.size() > 0) {
    for (Quote__c quote : quotes) {
        quote.Sys_checkchild__c = true;
        ...any other logic applied to individual Quotes
    }
}
```

Comment: Might help if you explain the distinction between id = 'xxx' and id IN()

Comment: @Ivan it showing an error : Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST<Quote__c> at line 36 column 1

Comment: List<Quote__c> quotes = [select id, name, Sys_checkchild__c from Quote__c where Id IN :quoteidset ];
if (quotes.size() > 0) { / error pointquotes.Sys_checkchild__c =true; }

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Above approach should be used regardless of the type of WHERE clause. Even if you are querying with `id = 'xxx'` and assigning result directly to an object, then if no result is found 'List has no rows for assignment' exception will be generated.

Comment: @Sathya `quotes` is a list of `Quote__c` objects. It can potentially contain more than one quote. You need to loop through all of it's elements set `Sys_checkchild__c` field on each record individually.

Comment: @ivan can give some code how can i solve this issuse

Comment: @Sathya see my updated answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14262/discussion-between-sathya-and-ivan)

Comment: @ivan can you check my code my all update field is updaing but my check box is not checking.

Comment: @ivan what is problem with my code..

Comment: @Sathya I can't help you without seeing the code you are running, please update the question.

Comment: @Ivan can you check my updated code.